# Comprehensive list of filter string options in readLAS

Tags: r, las, lidr

Is there a comprehensive list of string based filters that the `lidR` package supports in `readLAS()`? For example:

- `filter = "-drop_z_below 0"`
- `filter = "-drop_withheld"`

I know there are many more ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The documentation of `readLAS()` gives you all the required information

> #### Details
>
> Filter: the `filter` argument allows filtering of the point cloud while reading files. [...] The available filters are those from LASlib and can be found by running the following command: `rlas:::lasfilterusage()`. (see also `rlas::read.las`)

So you can use `rlas:::lasfilterusage()`